# How do I style HTML5 canvas text to be bold and/or italic?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, typography

I'm printing text to a canvas in a pretty straight forward way:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "10pt Courier";
ctx.fillText("Hello World", 100, 100);
```

But how can I change the text to bold, italic or both? Any suggestions to fix that simple example?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation on `CanvasRenderingContext2D.font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font):

> The `CanvasRenderingContext2D.font` property of the Canvas 2D API specifies the current text style to use when drawing text. This string uses the same syntax as the [CSS font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) specifier.

So, that means any of the following will work:

```
ctx.font = "italic 10pt Courier";

ctx.font = "bold 10pt Courier";

ctx.font = "italic bold 10pt Courier";
```

Here are a couple of additional resources for more information:

- [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)
- [HTML5 canvas - the basics](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/)

Comment: Arg beat me to it, +1 Great site for more info, http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html#divingin

Comment: @Loktar Thanks for the link, included it in answer.

Comment: regarding underline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627133/is-it-possible-to-draw-text-decoration-underline-etc-with-html5-canvas-text

Comment: You can also specify the font weight: `ctx.font = "400 10pt Courier"`

Comment: Font weight via `ctx.font = "400 10pt Open Sans"` didn't work for me in Chrome using Calibri or Open Sans in latest browser versions

Comment: First two links are broken

Answer (score 16):

Just an additional heads up for anyone who stumbles across this: be sure to follow the order shown in the accepted answer.

I ran into some cross-browser issues when I had the wrong order.  Having "10px Verdana bold" works in Chrome, but not in IE or Firefox.  Switching it to "bold 10px Verdana" as indicated fixed those problems.  Double-check the order if you run into similar problems.

Comment: Chrome seems to have changed so that it is in-line with Firefox. See this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXNZxO

Answer (score 3):

If you need to allow for variations in formatting, you can set a font style, draw text, measure it using [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText), set a new style, and then draw the next block like this:

```js
// get canvas / context
var can = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d')

// draw first text
var text = '99%';
ctx.font = 'bold 12pt Courier';
ctx.fillText(text, 50, 50);

// measure text
var textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;

// draw second text
ctx.font = 'normal 12pt Courier';
ctx.fillText(' invisible', 50 + textWidth, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="250" height="150"></canvas>
```

#### Further Reading

- [MDN > Canvas > Drawing text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text)
- [formatting individual words with italics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24163211/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

Underline is not possible through any of the canvas methods or properties. But I did some work around to get it done. You can check it out @ http://scriptstock.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/html5-canvas-text-underline-workaround

You can find the implementation here http://jsfiddle.net/durgesh0000/KabZG/