# How do I make a <ul> or bullet in fabric.Text()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am looking for an example application that takes user input and inserts it into a  inside canvas with fabric.js. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find a lists in fabric.js example.

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.fillText` does not accept HTML markup.
A Canvas is a bitmap, it has nothing to do with HTML markup.
You can control font style as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158222/how-do-i-style-html5-canvas-text-to-be-bold-and-or-italic).

There are [libraries](http://www.canvastext.com/) that convert XML markup into `canvas.fillText` calls, maybe you could adapt one.

Answer (score 1):

I realized a better way to solve this issue was to draw a circle at the same height as the text, at radius 2, to emulate a bullet point. for anybody interested its easy as:

```
var EDU1 = new fabric.IText("SOME TEXT GOES HERE", {fontSize: 20, fontStyle:                        
'italic',fontFamily: 'Hoefler Text', left: 149, top: 390});

var bullet = new fabric.Circle({
radius: 2, fill: 'black', left: 135, top: 400
});
```

then group them together and you have a bullet point.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ListStyle (textObject,type,canvas) {
  var styles=['\u25CF','\u25C8','\u25D8','\u25BA','\u25CB','\u25A0','-'];
  var allStyles={'bullet':'\u25CF','diamond':'\u25C8','invertedBullet':'\u25D8','triangularBullet':'\u25BA','disced':'\u25CB','squared':'\u25A0','dashed':'-','none':''};
  var text = textObject.text;
  var textArray = text.split('\n')
  var tempStr = [];
    textArray.forEach((text, i) => {
      if(styles.includes(text.substr(0,1))){
        tempStr.push(text.replace(text.substr(0,1),allStyles[type]));
      }else{
        tempStr.push(allStyles[type]+''+text);
      }
    })
  textObject['text'] = tempStr.join('\n');
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

ListStyle (canvas.getObjects()[0],'diamond',canvas);