# How can i draw smooth text on html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas, draw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Poor anti-aliasing of text drawn on Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262174/poor-anti-aliasing-of-text-drawn-on-canvas)

i already have drawn text on html canvas. but the text's side is not smooth. I want to make them smooth like photoshop. Please provide me sample javascript code to smooth the font text.

Here is my sample text: [click here to see what i want](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ITo_sdeeUME/T79vFQiJh4I/AAAAAAAAADo/V8tiBbCkTNk/s293/to-make-smooth-side-of-text.jpg)