# Blurry Text in HTML (Full example)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this very simple text centered inside the canvas.

My problem is that it looks terrible and blurry. How can I improve this?

```js
// Fill The signature canvas with information
var canvas = document.getElementById("signatureCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "12px sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Signature 1", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
```

```css
.signatureCanvas {
  border: 1px solid #027C8C;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="signatureCanvas" class="signatureCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262174/poor-anti-aliasing-of-text-drawn-on-canvas

Comment: the text isn't actually blurry, but because you resize the canvas out of it's dimensions (`width: 100%`) it will become blurry. Basically what you're doing is creating an image and resizing it (enlarging in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Set the `width` and `height` attributes of `canvas` dynamically inside your JS code instead of using the style rules `width/height` :

```js
// Fill The signature canvas with information
var canvas = document.getElementById("signatureCanvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "12px sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Signature 1", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
```

```css
.signatureCanvas {
  border: 1px solid #027C8C;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="signatureCanvas" class="signatureCanvas"></canvas>
```