# How to remove edginess of text when rendered with HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So, I'm having trouble finding out how to fix the edginess of the [text rendered with fillText function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFAv2.png) The [text looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9hRz.png) if it is rendered with the DOM instead of the canvas however I need to render it using the canvas instead.

Edit: I found out what's wrong with the way I render the text. It was all about the animation loop as I didn't clear the canvas before re-rendering the text. So when I render the text once, [it looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKsPk.png) (text on top is rendered with DOM, bottom text rendered with canvas). But when I put it in an animation loop it becomes [messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yinvb.png) (same kind of image but canvas text looks bad).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem. (Because otherwise, we'd have to create one ourselves first to fiddle around with, and that's quite time-consuming...)

Comment: Also, this could be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262174/poor-anti-aliasing-of-text-drawn-on-canvas/26154753)

Comment: Wow how come you don't have **any** antialiasing? Are you using some `image-rendering`  css rule or a `filter`? Just remove it if so, text is naturally antialiased on canvas (using transparency antialiasing by default and ways to force subpixel on some configs).